# Parser for ignoring nested parentheses?

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I was wondering how I could incorporate a parser for ignoring nested parentheses when matching patterns. I am trying to ignore the nested parentheses in a pattern like (a(b))_n. This is not possible now because my pattern matches the content inside the first parentheses by matching everything but a ')'. Would I use a for loop? And how would I detect only the nested parentheses inside the first parentheses? I don't have an idea of where to start. Thanks.

Comment: Look at the some of the question in the _related_ list on the right.

Comment: If the parentheses are only nested 1 deep every time, you could match the inner parentheses by using, `\(([^()]+)\)`

Comment: @MElliott, how would that match the inner parentheses though ? Wouldn't the ^() be telling it to match anything but parentheses?

Comment: @user2825125, well, it's matching the contents inside the parentheses that don't have parentheses inside. Hence the `[^()]+`. Take a look at it here: http://regex101.com/r/lO7gN7

Comment: @MElliott, oh okay. Thanks, but its only matching the contents inside the inner parentheses. Is there a way to match everything inside the outer parentheses, including the nested parentheses?

Comment: @user2825125, of course. - `\((.*)\)`

Answer (score 0):

To handle this, you generally need to have a "stack like" handling of these things. If you are only going to recognize a pattern, the "stack" might be a simple counter to keep track of the current parenthesis level (increment/decrement it as you parse the text).

Regular expressions cannot be used for this, this is a limitation from what can be expressed in a *regular language*.

Comment: thanks! so would I use a method like string.contains to parse the string for a parentheses?

Comment: I would go for a `for each char in string do ... done` approach.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Is there a way to do this only in a specific group of the matcher, such as inside the outer parentheses?